# Header and footer not working properly on safari (SWF + image)

Tags: html, css, safari

am having a big problem on safar
have an swf object in the header , and a big image in the left near the footer , both are not aligned well and i did't succeed to fix it on safari without leaving chrome and IE unharmed :(

any ideas ? tips ?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The swf files looks fine in Safari. As for the gallery on the bottom, the preview image has shifted to the left... is that what you meant? If so, it would be helpful if you'd show the code.